# Can a set with a cardinality $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ be ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathbb Z$ has a natural order. $\mathbb R$ has one too. $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ can be ordered by first comparing the left index and then, if left-equal, comparing the right index. That scheme for ordering can be extended to $\mathbb R^{n}$ for any $n$ in the obvious way. It can be extended to $\mathbb {R^N}$ by defining equality as when the process of comparing successive tuple elements never terminates with a greater-than or a less-than. However, moving up to $\mathbb{R^R}$ my confidence wanes, and it becomes no longer clear that such a process would be well-defined. For example, if I were to try and encode the comparison process in the language of functions like this:

> $f > g$ iff for the least $x$ for which $f(x)\neq g(x)$, $f(x)\gt g(x)$

> $f < g$ iff for the least $x$ for which $f(x)\neq g(x)$, $f(x)\lt g(x)$

> $f = g$ iff for all $x$ $f(x)=g(x)$

Then it would be unclear what the comparison of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ should be, because there is no least $x$ for which they are unequal.

Can an order like this be constructed for sets as big as $\mathbb{R^R}$? Of course I mean to rule out trivial orders like "everything is equal." Two elements of the set should only be equal if they are actually the same element.

Comment: you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem

Comment: I gather you mean a total order on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, am I right?

Comment: @Mihail There does not need to be a least element for an order to make sense. For example, what's the least element of $\mathbb R$? For any $x$, there is $x-1$. So my goal could be satisfied whether or not you have well-ordering.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, a strict total order. Although this question is secretly a soft question, because if the answer is no for strict total orders I would still like to know what the strongest possible order is.

Comment: @Retracted nevertheless it answers your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is what exactly do you mean by this.

Assuming the axiom of choice, every set can be well-ordered, and in particular linearly ordered. The statement "every set can be linearly ordered" is itself weaker than the axiom of choice, but assuming it, we can of course prove that there exists a linear ordering on any set, in particular $\Bbb{R^R}$.

But we can also understand this question as "can we define an explicit total order on $\Bbb{R^R}$?", which we can also understand as "Does $\sf ZF$ prove that $\Bbb{R^R}$ can be linearly ordered?"

And the answer to that is negative. It is consistent that there is a subset of $\Bbb{R^R}$ which cannot be linearly ordered. In some models of $\sf ZF$ we can even make an explicit such a set: $\sf ZF$ does not prove that $\Bbb{R/Q}$ can be linearly ordered, and we can consider this as a set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to itself by noting that $\Bbb{R/Q\subseteq\mathcal P(R)}$.

As to your "secretly soft question", there is no notion of "strongest order", because linear orders are exactly the maximal partial orders on a set, so a partial order is either linear or can be extended by at least one more comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for cardinality.

$f>g$ if the cardinality of the set for which $f(x)>g(x)$ is greater than the cardinality of the set for which $f(x) < g(x)$

$f<g$ if the cardinality of the set for which $f(x)<g(x)$ is greater than the cardinality of the set for which $f(x) > g(x)$

otherwise $f=g$